# TableViewController wait loading data before objectAtIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have this code to load data from **Parse** in a TableView with Swift.
The problem I have :

- When I touch a cell, that's open the detail view with the cell infos
   But when I return to the list view and touch another cell to fast, the data are not loaded and I have an error :

> NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2
>   beyond bounds for empty array'

How could I force waiting the view to load all the cell data before I can touch something ?
I can put the loadData() call in the viewDidLoad method, but this way I'll be force to refresh manually the data each time I add a new cell, delete a cell...etc

```
class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

   var alertsListData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

   func loadData(){
       alertsListData.removeAllObjects()
       var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
       if (currentUser != nil){
           var findAlertsData = PFQuery(className: "Alert")
           findAlertsData.whereKey("user_id", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser())
           findAlertsData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
               (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)-> Void in
               if (error == nil){
                   for object in objects {
                       self.alertsListData.addObject(object)
                   }
                   self.tableView.reloadData()
                   self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
               }
           }
       }
   }

   @IBAction func logoutAction(sender: AnyObject) {
       PFUser.logOut()
       var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
   }

   override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {        
       self.loadData()
       ...
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       var refresh = UIRefreshControl()
       refresh.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Tirer pour rafraîchir")
       refresh.addTarget(self, action: "loadData", forControlEvents:.ValueChanged)
       self.refreshControl = refresh

       // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
       //self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

       // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
       // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   // MARK: - Table view data source

   override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
       // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
       // Return the number of sections.
           return 1
   }

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
       // Return the number of rows in the section.
       return alertsListData.count
   }

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell:AlertTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath:    indexPath) as AlertTableViewCell
       let alert:PFObject = self.alertsListData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject
       cell.alertTitleLabel.text = alert.objectForKey("title") as? String
       var dateUpdated = alert.updatedAt as NSDate
       var dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
       dateFormat.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "fr_FR")
       dateFormat.dateFormat = "EEEE d, à hh:mm"
       cell.alertDateLabel.text = NSString(format: "%@", dateFormat.stringFromDate(dateUpdated).capitalizedString)
       var status:Bool = alert.objectForKey("status") as Bool
       if (status == true){
           cell.alertStatus.text = "Terminée"
       }else{
           cell.alertStatus.text = "En cours"
       }

       return cell
   }

   /*
   // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
       // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
       return true
   }
   */

   /*
   // Override to support editing the table view.
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle,    forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
       if editingStyle == .Delete {
           // Delete the row from the data source
           tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
       } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
           // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
       }    
   }
   */

   /*
   // Override to support rearranging the table view.
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath!, toIndexPath:    NSIndexPath!) {

   }
   */

   /*
   // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
       // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
       return true
   }
   */


   // MARK: - Navigation

   // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject!) {
       // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
       // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
       if (segue!.identifier == "showDetails"){
           var selectedIndexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
           var detailViewController:DetailViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
           detailViewController.alertData = alertsListData.objectAtIndex(selectedIndexPath.row) as PFObject
       }
   }

   }
```

The Add controller is :

```
class AddViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var urlTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        var toAdd = PFObject(className:"Alert")
        toAdd["title"] = titleTextField.text
        toAdd["user_id"] = PFUser.currentUser()
        toAdd["status"] = false
        toAdd.saveInBackground()
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can toggle on and off user interaction, until data is received and reloaded?

```
self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Also move `self.loadData()` to `viewDidLoad` you don't need to re-download each time you go back

Comment: It's an idea, but I'm sure there is better things to do... I heard about asynchronously loading, what's that ? Also, if I try your solution, how I can know if data are received or not ?

Comment: Aren't you downloading data asynchronously? it just mean you start a background thread to download data this way you dont block the UI thread.
When that happens its up to you display a message for example `loading data..` then once completed reload and allow interaction

Comment: Yes, in fact it's already async. How can I wait the data is loaded to display the list of cell ?

Comment: the list of cell will not display until the tableView is reloaded. My suggestion is to show `activity indicator +  disable interaction` untill reloaded then hide indicator an reenable the interaction. does it make sense ?

Comment: @user2178964 Also move self.loadData() to viewDidLoad you don't need to re-download each time you go back

Comment: In fact I agree it's a better solution to put the loadData method in viewDidLoad method. But how reload data after a adding action or delete action. For example I click on "Add", I add m'y alert, I'm redirected on the master view controller, but I tell him to reload ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63255/discussion-between-meda-and-user2178964).